# Is "forgive" di-transitive?

Tags: ditransitive-verbs

I know that I can say

> We would forgive the mistake (that) he has made.

I am wondering if I can reword this into

> We would forgive him **the mistake (that) he has made**.

I have seen a few of such ditransitive structures on the internet and I am not 100 percent sure weather it is a proper English. Any discussion is appreciated.

Comment: Yes! *We would forgive him the mistake (that) he has made* is perfectly idiomatic. We forgive *people*, not *mistakes*. It is similar to *And forgive us our trespasses*, from the Lord's Prayer. (*Trespasses* means *sins*.)

Comment: Yes, I think that rewording works. Forgive is di-transitive, e.g. "Forgive us our sins." I found a PDF paper with a lot of words about di-transitive "forgive", including more than I wanted to read (chapter 2, page 15). See https://tinyurl.com/y87eqfdd

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can absolutely do that.  It is perfectly idiomatic